# Запятая или двоеточие? Оба?

Tags: пунктуация

Оба правильны?

`Привет. Можешь сказать, где по информатике практические задания, которые нам в Word'е надо сделать-таки?`

`Привет. Можешь сказать: где по информатике практические задания, которые нам в Word'е надо сделать-таки?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Грамматика** верная в обоих случаях, но **по стилю** больше подходит такой вариант:

*Привет. **Можешь сказать, где** по информатике практические задания, которые нам в Word'е надо сделать-таки?*

**[Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=88#pp88)**

**Вопросительный знак** ставится в конце сложноподчиненного предложения, если **вопрос содержится и в главной, и в придаточной частях предложения или только в главной части, либо в придаточно**й: Вы знаете, что такое сестры милосердия? (Остр.); Всякого рода нарушения, уклонения, отступления от правил приводили его в уныние, хотя, казалось бы, какое ему дело? (Ч.)

**Примечание.** Если придаточная часть сложноподчиненного предложения содержит косвенный вопрос, то в конце предложения вопросительный знак обычно **не ставится**: Я прервал речь Савельича вопросом, сколько у меня всего денег (П.); Корчагин неоднократно спрашивал меня, когда он может выписаться (Н. О.).

Однако, если косвенный вопрос содержит **сильно выраженную вопросительную интонацию,** в конце сложноподчиненного предложения **ставится вопросительный знак**: Скажите, пожалуйста, что это за огни? (Л. Т.); Я спросил, как же он стал отшельником? (М. Г.)

Comment: Дело в том, что главное-то у меня предложение вопросительное, следовательно нужно ставить обязательно вопросительный знак.

Comment: Я ставлю вопросительный знак по Розенталю, а выбор предложения делаю по стилю. Вариант с БСП – книжный стиль, а мне нужен разговорный.

Comment: Кстати, обратие внимание на три основы. Это предложение можно разделить на два блока, хотя особой необходимости в этом нет. Но тем не менее, просто для интереса. Как вы думаете, какие это блоки, где граница?

Comment: Перед *Можете сказать*, перед *которые* и после него.

Comment: Я думаю так: Можешь сказать, гдЕ по информатике практические задАния, // которые нам в Word'е надо сдЕлать-таки? Здесь "можешь сказать" на правах вводного слова, а граница перед "которые". Это по интонации можно определить, Отношения между блоками определительные, обозначены запятой.

Answer (score -1):

Если судить по примерам из литературы:

> Спрашивается, куда они девались? или лучше сказать: где причина такой наклонности земледельческой промышленности к упадку? Фет.

> А с другой стороны, и то надо сказать: где же и ораторы такие бывают, как у нас?

> Но и то сказать: где предел исторических подробностей. В. Н. Майков.

> А с другой стороны, и то надо сказать: где же и ораторы такие бывают, как у нас? Добролюбов.

То есть нужна или предикация - лучше, надо и тп.; или или усиление вроде "и то".

Привет, можешь главное сказать: где по информатике практические задания, которые нам в Word'е надо сделать-таки?

Но смысл само собой будет: спроси вот это вот.

Проблема в том, что когда ты даешь некие предложения, ты никак не даешь контекста. Ты спрашиваешь, такая форма или нет. Форма не определяет грамматику, так что нужно сказать: что ты хочешь сказать-то, об чём речь?

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149029/discussion-on-answer-by-----); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.